# update or not send undefined params in url

Tags: angular

I have GET request with params and I want send param only if they aren't undefined

**OF COURSE without any `if` condition in each my method !!**

Considering this :

```
  getPeriodesComptable(immeubleId: any, periodeDeLaDate?: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`okay`, {params:{includeDate: date}});
  }
```

How can I send param **includeDate** only if **date** isn't undefined?

My endpoint spring waiting number/date and can't recieve undefined but null.

Actually I don't have something like in spring/hibernate "send null=false" in json.  How can I achieve this.

ps: i actually have an `AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor` but trying to do something like this NOT works ?:

```
 req.clone({
        params:req.params.keys().forEach(x=> {
          if(req.params.get(x) == undefined)
            req.params.delete(x)
        })
      })
```

This next code works but I wanted avoid creating new HttpParams() :

```
 let cleanedParams = new HttpParams();
      req.params.keys().forEach(x => {
        if(req.params.get(x) != undefined)
          cleanedParams = cleanedParams.append(x, req.params.get(x));
      })

      const clonedRequest = req.clone({
        params:cleanedParams,
      });
      return next.handle(clonedRequest)
```

If someone have cleaner/faster way to achieve this, really appreciate.

Comment: I think your approach using `HttpInterceptor` is fine. What is the reason you want to avoid creating `HttpParams` ?

Comment: wanted something less verbose, more optimized, think will go with this approach if no better one

Comment: Another option would be to create a wrapper over `HttpClient` where you filter out undefined values

Comment: yes know about it too, anyway I opened issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20564 thanks at all

Comment: Hi any solution you got for this..????